# visual studio intellisense: xml comment contains invalid xml: a name contained an invalid character

Tags: xml, visual-studio, intellisense

Can anyone tell me where the heck the problem is?! Visual Studio 2019 tells me "xml comment contains invalid xml: a name contained an invalid character" when the Intellisense tries to pull up.

```
/// <summary>Initializes the WCS_AutoSolver class including performing source extraction on a given FITS image.</summary>
/// <param name="WCS_type">The WCS tranformation type. Solution only uses TAN at this time.</param>
/// <param name="Number_of_Points">The number of points N to use to compare image coordinates to catalogue coordinates. Suggest N = 10 for good correspondence, N = 50 for poor, N = 100 for very poor.</param>
/// <param name="Fits_Image_File">The full path file name of the FITS image to search for point sources.</param>
/// <param name="Image_ROI">The region of interest of the FITS image to search for point sources, of identical size to the FITS image. Pass nullptr or all true for entire image.</param>
/// <param name="Image_Saturation">The saturation level of the source image for mapping saturated sources. Pass zero if no saturated sources exist.</param>
/// <param name="PSE_kernel_radius">The radius of the point-source-extraction kernel, in pixels. PSEkernel_radius greater than or equal to 1.</param>
/// <param name="PSE_separation_radius">The minimum separation of point sources, in pixels. PSESeparation_radius greater than or equal to PSEkernel_radius.</param>
/// <param name="Fits_Catalogue_BinTable_File">The full path file name of the FITS binary table containing the catalogue data.</param>
/// <param name="Catalogue_Extension_Name">The extension name of the FITS binary table which contains the catalogue data. If empty string is passed then the first binary table extension is assumed.</param>
/// <param name="Catalogue_CVAL1_Name">The name of the entry inside the binary table which lists the CVAL1 (i.e. right ascension) coordinates.</param>
/// <param name="Catalogue_CVAL2_Name">The name of the entry inside the binary table which lists the CVAL2 (i.e. declination) coordinates.</param>
/// <param name="Catalogue_Magnitude_Name">The name of the entry inside the binary table which lists the source magnitudes.</param>
```

Comment: try to delete .vs hidden folder under your solution.

Comment: No this did not help.

Comment: What is your vs version?

Comment: The latest version. All updates are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

> visual studio intellisense: xml comment contains invalid xml: a name
>   contained an invalid character

This is quite an abnormal behavior for your project. **In my side**, when I add these in a similar function, the **Intellisense** works well and does not turn out any errors.

[image]

So I am afraid that there are some problems with your vs environment, please try these steps:

**Note** that this xml document works for the specific function in code editor.

**Suggestion**

1. close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin`, `obj` folder, restart your project and then test again.
2. clean vs component caches-----delete files under `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx\ComponentModelCache`
3. [do a repair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) in VS Installer
4. if your VS is not the latest version, please try to update it in case there are some fixes.

Comment: Besides, try to disable any third party extensions under `Manage Extensions` or just use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019)(start VS) to test whether it is caused by any third party packages.

Comment: I'm not using any 3rd party extensions.

I tried steps 1 & 2 and the problem remains.

Comment: To test this issue, I suggest you create a new project and then add these xml document into it, if the project still face this issue, try to do a repair, if it not, there is an issue in your project and you should check it or create a new class file to replace it.